# C++ SFML mouse movement

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to detect mouse movement event and move it back to the middle of the screen using sf::RenderWindow pollEvent method and detect the event type sf::Event::MousePressed. The problem is when I'm detecing the mouse movment I need to move the mouse back to the middle of the screen and for that im using sf::Mouse::setPosition but I think (maybe I'm wrong) that function itself calling sf::Event::MouseMoved when it used, and im afraid it creates an infinite loop.

Exmaple of the way im doing that: (I know 0, 0 it's not the middle it is just and exmaple)

```
while (app.pollEvent(Event))
{
  if(Event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved)
        {
            sf::Mouse::setPosition(0 , 0));
        }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is giving you problems, just add a check that mouse is not at (0, 0), before moving it there.

Comment: Please don't move the mouse! It's horrible and not user-friendly at all. Seriously, don't do it. You also wouldn't run into this problem (because I'm sure the function was not intended for such usage).

Comment: So what I'm supposed to do instead? I want to check every frame the delta of the mouse movement by subtract the mouse position by the position of the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `app.SetCursorPosition(x, y);` instead.

Also, i would skip the check for events, since you will want the cursor to end in the middle at the end of each frame anyway.

Comment: I check for events because I also rotate the camera there and then return the mouse to the middle of the screen

Comment: If you are trying to create FPP (first-person perspective) camera, I recommend you use `sf::Input` instead of mouse events.